# Replacing Apostrophe in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to replace a single quote or apostrophe in Applescript through a shell script but I am having a hard time escaping the single quote.

**set ComputerName to do shell script "echo " & Name & " | tr -d '"**

I keep on getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
set ComputerName to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of Name & " | tr -d \\' "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through shell script like this:

```
set ComputerName to do shell script "tr -d \\' <<<" & name's quoted form
```

(but I suggest you choose a different variable label than `name`, which has a special significance in AppleScript and can generate errors).

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing using plain AppleScript:

```
set my text item delimiters to {pi, "'"}
set ComputerName to the text items of name as text
```

(Unless your variable happens to contain pi in it, which seems unlikely.)